# How to overwrite the default behavior for the form.serialize() method so that it serializes the Multiselect widget rather than the Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI Multiselect to place a multiselect dropdownlist on the page.

I'm using the form.Serialize() method and it serializes the fomr and adds only the first item in the list so it serializes like "Client=1" rather than "Client=1&Client=2"

If I use below directly, again it only serializes one item:

```
$("#Client").serialize()
```

How to overwrite the default behavior for the form.serialize() method so that it serializes the Multiselect widget rather than the Drop Down List.

The multiselect is configured like this:

```
var multiSelOptions = {
        checkAll: optionChanged,
        uncheckAll: optionChanged,
        click: optionChanged,
        checkAllText: 'labelForCheckAll',
        uncheckAllText: 'labelForUnCheckAll',
        noneSelectedText: 'labelForPleaseSelect',
        selectedText: '# selected',
        selectedList: 1,
        header: true,
        multiple: true,
        minWidth: 176
    };

 $('#Client').multiselect(multiSelOptions);
```

JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/UQCuk/3

Comment: Client is the id/name of the select drop down list.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, but can't get it configured there

Comment: See sample working here: http://jsfiddle.net/UQCuk/4/

Comment: It serializes fine in your example: http://jsfiddle.net/UQCuk/6/

Comment: Ya but see how it is ugly. In fact this plugin seems not to support natively any serialize method. Maybe you should check DOC for any option regarding this

Comment: But in mine, I'm only adding a reference to the jquery multiselect js files. Are you serializing anything manually? are you overwriting the serialization manually?

Comment: I update native select (setted to multiple) depending plugin selected elements. Then serialize it